# cant run my spider trough scrapy cloud with php curl

Tags: php, curl, scrapy

i can't get it to connect my `php` to my `spiders`

```
$url = 'https://app.scrapinghub.com/api/jobs/list.json';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
CURLOPT_URL => $url,

CURLOPT_POST => 1,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
    'project' => 'projecid',
    'spider' => 'spiderid',
),

CURLOPT_USERPWD => "apikey")

);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo '<pre>';
print $response;
echo '</pre>';
```

​it returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 400 method not allowed
Server: nginx/1.10.1
Date: Fri, 07 Jul 2017 07:24:02 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 57
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Cookie
Set-Cookie: csrftoken2=67xgaAQB9ytsIYNxseDFAIUzkCivPZMda74Hvg7UNMp6iD3zALRDWP6zhknxiEIP; Domain=.scrapinghub.com; expires=Fri, 06-Jul-2018 07:24:02 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; Secure
X-Upstream: dash-master_apiv1

{"status": "badrequest", "message": "method not allowed"}
```

it says `bad request` means i am wrong with my `url`  but in the docs it said it should be like these or i am wrong on sending my `apikey`.

please help me here thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a `POST` request to scrapinghub which is the `message` of your `badrequest` status as `method not allowed`. instead you can try sending a `GET` request through PHP curl like so

```
$url = 'https://app.scrapinghub.com/api/jobs/list.json';
$ch = curl_init();
$curl_opts = array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url."?project=projectid&spider=spiderid",
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => "apikey"
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $curl_opts);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo '<pre>';
print $response;
echo '</pre>';
```